# np.gentext loop and fill empty array in python

Tags: python, loops

I have 50 different folders (from 0 to 50) with the data I want to plot named as data_A, data_B, data_C, data_D.
How do I iterate through the 50 folders, collect the data, apply a numerical operation and print the output (V) to a list?
The final goal would be to make a boxplot of (V) for each folder.

Hope that this attempt of code helps in understanding my aim:

```
directory='/path_to_data/'

folders = [0..50]

for i in (len(folders)):
        A = (np.genfromtxt(directory/[i]/'data_A.dat')
        B = (np.genfromtxt(directory/[i]/'data_B.dat')
        C = (np.genfromtxt(directory/[i]/'data_C.dat') 
        D = (np.genfromtxt(directory/[i]/'data_D.dat') 

        V = (A+B+C+D)/4 #make and average of the data
        
    DATA=[V,..]
    NAMES=[folder$i,.. ]
done
```

Thanks!

Comment: `directory/[i]/'data_A.dat'` must be a string that is a valid path. So, combine directory, i, and file name into a string that represents a valid file path. The specifics depend on your file system. The subsequent operations are even more opaque. How do you want to average these four numpy arrays?

Comment: It is a valid path and the subsequent operation is just a mean, but that's not the main issue. My question would be more on how to loop or iterate with np.genfromtxt and create an empty array where to append the values